# sum function in GREL in OpenRefine

Tags: openrefine, grel

In OpenRefine, I'm trying to increase the value of every number in a column by 1.

The GREL expression `sum([value],1)` gives me `Error: sum expects an array of numbers`.

I guess I don't know how to produce an array of numbers. When I use a different function on the same column, such as `tan([value])`, I get the result I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the use of `sum()`. If you just want to add 1 to each cell, just use `value + 1`.

[image]

Make sure, however, that your column contains numbers (in green) and not strings (in black). If in doubt, use `toNumber(value) + 1` instead.

The `sum()` function allows to add all the numbers contained in an array, for instance `sum([1,2,3,4]) = 10`, but you have no array if each cell of your column contains a unique number.

Comment: Great, thanks! Blindingly obvious now that I see it. This works better than the incorrect solution I thought I'd found, `sum([value,1])`, which gave me a result of 1 in empty cells, which I did not want. The documentation for GREL is surprisingly sparse.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Added better mention of that. Fixed now https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Cell-Editing